# Receiving emails from 2 domains in google workspace with only 1 account

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace

I have 2 domains

```
mydomain.com
mydomain.com.au
```

I have a Google Workspace account for the `.com.au` domain, it has an email which is `myemail@mydomain.com.au` .. The MX records are set and its all working correctly.

I have recently bought the `.com`, I want to setup a `myemail@mydomain.com` email address and just forward that to the `myemail@mydomain.com.au` email address.

Is there a way to do this without purchasing another Google Workspace account?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. You can try out the following steps to solve your problem:

1. Login to Google Workspace and select Domains in the admin console.
2. Then you need to add a domain alias. This is done by clicking on your existing domain (mydomain.com.au). From there you are able to add a domain alias and enter your new domain (mydomain.com)
3. Follow the next steps and verify the ownership of your domains.
4. After verification it should be straight forward, go to the User section and select the email you want to work on (myemail@mydomain.com.au).
5. Select email aliases from there and add your wished email alias and enter it (myemail@mydomains.com).
6. Follow the promts again and save the changes.